# Create an instance of one of several derived classes depending on the execution of code in their shared base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I want to execute some generic code and initialise variables that are common to a number of classes. It makes sense to do all this work in a base class. Based on the data created, I then want to execute some code that's specific to a particular function. I feel these functions should be in classes derived from the base class. However, I also want to be able to gain access to the data that was initialised in the base class.

Something like this:

```
class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        public int _earCount = 2;
        // determine if the planet is all water or all land
    }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public WagEars()
    {
    // for each ear, execute code to wag it
    }
}

class Whale : Animal
{
    public FlipTail()
    {
    // code to flip
    }
}

public main()
{
    Animal fred = new Animal;
    // what code goes here to invoke WagEars if the planet is all land?
}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is execute common header/footer-type code for all objects with some derived-class-specific code in the middle.

When fred is created, I do not know whether it will be a dog or whale until the common code has been executed.

Comment: When fred is created, either it's a dog, or it's a whale, or it's neither. If inheritance is used to solve this, then something has to know at the point of creation.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is something like the following:

```
public main()
{
    Dog fred = new Dog();
    fred.WagEars();
}
```

In order to call methods of a subclass, you need to declare the type of the variable to be that class.

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
public main()
{
    Animal fred = new Dog();
    ((Dog)fred).WagEars();
}
```

If you down cast the object to the correct subclass, you will gain access to the subclass' methods.

Comment: InvalidCastException on the second case, because `fred` is **not** a Dog.

Comment: @JonHanna Whoops, I did that a bit wrong. Check out my edit, and thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
if(fred is Dog)
{
  ((Dog)fred).WagEars();
}

if(fred is Whale)
{
  ((Whale)fred).FlipTail();
}
```